# Foreach com OrderBy pelo campo Ordem

Tags: wordpress

Eu estou tentando fazer um order by de um foreach pela ordem das categorias mas não vai!

```
<ul class="categories-legend">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'order' => 'DESC' //this is the default as well
        );
        $category = get_terms($args);

        foreach($dashboard_categories as $category):
            $color = carbon_get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'gp_category_color');
    ?>
    <li class="categories-legend-item" style="color:<?php echo $color;?>"><span><?php echo $category->name; ?></span></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Como assim você está tentando fazer um `orderBy` de um `foreach`?

Comment: Esse foreach não ta invertido não?

Comment: Verdade @DarleiFernandoZillmer.